# Caching data with frequently changed fields, what are the best solutions?

Tags: caching, architecture, backend, system, feed

I'm currently implementing a news feed feature in our application, where an user should be able to query a number of posts that were pre-generated for them and were cached in redis.

The problem is, each post contains a lot of fields that are frequently updated (number of likes, comments, etc...) and if I run these write operations to redis itself, I'm afraid it would affects the read performance, since there are very large number of users currently using our application.

Do you recommend any solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you simply cache only that part of the page which is fairly static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a few seconds can help greatly. I set most API objects to at least 3-5 seconds.

Here are some best practices recommended from AWS:

https://aws.amazon.com/caching/best-practices/